# How to customise Google chrome to add search options on a right click?

Tags: search, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As short cuts, I have added various search engine entries in my browser to get to a page having a patterned URL easily.

But this still does not solve the problem completely. While browsing, if I see some text that corresponds to one of the pages, I need to copy the text, open a new tab and then use my search entry to go to that page.

A couple of steps can be saved if I can directly right click and go to the search engine.

How can I do that? Do I need to create an extension for this or something simpler can help?

> Current:
>
> 1. copy text
> 2. open new tab
> 3. search engine keyword followed by tab
> 4. paste text
> 5. press return
>
> Desired:
>
> 1. select text
> 2. right click and select search

Comment: Are you willing to recompile chrome and/or change values with a hexeditor?

Comment: @Alexander, why would he do that? @Lazer This seems more like a Super User question, except you're willing to write it yourself if no add on is available. Did you try Context Menu Search?

Comment: The step 2 is actually two steps. 2. Right click  3. Select search

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can *add* context menu items via Chrome extensions - see [the doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) for more details.

However, there's no current way to remove core-Chrome context menu items; only ones created by your own extension. And from researching before, I also think there's no way to get a user's search engines - only hardcode the ones you want.

Comment: This answer was posted 3 years ago, is this still true?

Comment: @turner It seems to still be the case, and it's not likely to change.

Comment: I wonder why? Anyway, I found out that you can suppress the right-click function for elements on a webpage and then you'd have to code your own right-click functionality if you wanted to make a custom context menu.

Answer (score 5):

Install the [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga) Add on in Google Chrome

Comment: +1 Haven't tried it, but from the description it seems to be doing exactly what's asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Chrome 11.0.696.71  as my browser , and I have not installed any addons. I have set Google as the default search engine.

However when searching,  I select the text, right click , and in the context menu I have have the search option, please see screenshot.
[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an extension like Context Menu Search: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga

Answer (score 2):

Here's another extension that I believe does what you're looking for...

I built it and I welcome your feedback! :)

[Simple=Select+Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aagminaekdpcfimcbhknlgjmpnnnmooo)

Answer (score 1):

I use SearchCenter....
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ndfplmdnbnefomnjiknbpejdceedhdmf

Answer (score 1):

Like this >[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuu4c.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuu4c.png
Simple,

1) Find,download and install a chrome extension that supports this feature.

2) Edit the js files as text files.

3) Replace all the original links in the plug in with the link of the search engine that you want to use.

4) Add the new extension with a different name.

done

Comment: Hi, how could I find the js files?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about that other extension but this one is exactly what you are asking for:

Multi-Search

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afmdpmddiokpdknaeofdnlclbpgehhce

It comes with preset searches but you can easily modify what you want through the options tab.

For example, I changed my settings and added The Free Dictionary dot com as the top line item in the sub menu. IMDB and Google and a few others are there by default but you can add or remove as you please.

Really excellent. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for an extension that can search the text in a URL link. So if the link is "www.example.com" and the hyperlink text is "Example", I want to be able to right click on the link and search "Example" via my custom search engines.

I can do this in Firefox easily using the "Context Search Origin" addon (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/context-search-we/), but need something similar for Chrome. Closest thing I found for Chrome is this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menus/phlfmkfpmphogkomddckmggcfpmfchpn

But it searches the link URL instead of the link text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install an extension if you just want, for example, "Search Google for ...". If you go to Settings -> Manage search engines and you click on the little three-dot settings-icon on the line that says  Google (or Bing, or Yahoo or whatever) in the list of "Default search engines", and choose "Make default", then the "Search Google for ..." starts appearing in the right-click menu (what I call the context menu)